# How to show reports on sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, report

i have the sharepoint site , infact it is MOSS site. I want to show the reports on share point site. Is there any facility available for to do so? Or is i need to develop any webpart for same? please guide.....
reply will appreciable....! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make web user controls and have gridview or any report that you want and upload it as a webpart.

let me know if you need further help.

Comment: ok fine... getting point. but, i want to show chart infat. i can build the webpart for chart , but problem is that i want to use sharepoint content database & want to query on that. is that possible ?

Comment: Hmm...what sort of data is that - can't you create a sql connection? Have you used sharepoint designer. 

A very good guide - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/ha101009081033.aspx


Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running MOSS you have a SQL Server which means you have a license for SQL Reporting Services (SRS).  SRS integrates with Sharepoint very nicely, one in standard mode (reports are hosted within SQL) and another mode called "integrated" where the reports are actaully housed within SharePoint and revisioned/versioned as such.  If SRS doesn't work for you use a page viewere web part to pass through the reports from the reporting engine of your choice.